# How can I read in a specific number of characters from a line? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, ifstream

I am working on a homework assignment where I need to error check the first line of a .txt file. In this case, the first line of the text file should read "Number of samples: ", followed by an unspecified number. If the line DOES NOT start with "Number of samples: ", I need to terminate the program after displaying an error message. Assuming that the line DOES start with the proper string, I need to read in the number as an unsigned integer.

In summary, I need to read in 19 characters from a .txt file line. How do I go about doing that, while still being able to read in the rest of the line to store it as a variable?

The libraries I'm using are iostream, string, ofstream, and ifstream if that matters.

Comment: Post a [example] that illustrates what you have so far so we can gauge your current understanding and help you to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ifstream x;
char addToString;
string check = "Number of samples: ";
string temp = "";
int num;
x.open("file.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++){
     x.get(addToString);
     temp += addToString;
}

if (check == temp){
     x >> num;
     // other stuff
}

else {
     cout << "error message" << endl;
}

x.close();

return 0;
```

Comment: Since your read of the unsigned value with ignore leading whitespace, you can save a character and simply use 18-chars -- `"Number of samples:"` as the intro test. `+=` is fine for concatenation, your alternative is `temp.push_back(std::cin.get());` Either work, up to you.

Comment: Always go with the more efficient method. I myself appreciate you pointing that out.